# Clutch fluid, DOT 4 Brake Fluid

Tags: honda, civic, clutch, fluid

1999 Honda Civic, 5-speed.  Don't have manual, yet. Is DOT 4 Brake Fluid recommended?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: What do you mean with clutch fluid?

Answer (score 2):

The [Honda Operator's Manual](https://techinfo.honda.com/rjanisis/pubs/om/CI0101/CI0101O00223A.pdf) states:

> Always use Honda DOT 3 brake fluid. If it is not available, you should use only DOT 3 or DOT 4 fluid, from a sealed container, as a temporary replacement. However, the use of
>   any non-Honda brake fluid can cause corrosion and decrease the life of the system. Have the brake system flushed and refilled with Honda DOT 3 brake fluid as soon as possible.

However, brake fluid is pretty much brake fluid, whether Honda makes it or Prestone does. There are certain properties it has to have. If it doesn't have those properties, it's not brake fluid. That being said, you can use DOT3 or DOT4 or DOT3/4 (sometimes listed this way on the bottle). Do not, however, use DOT5, as this is silicon based brake fluid and should not be used in place of the regular. The only difference between DOT3 & DOT4 is the boiling points, both wet and dry. The general makeup of it is pretty much the same, though.